# Compilation failure : cannot find symbol. While running Java code from CI jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, compilation, maven-plugin

I have been wandering around the internet to find a solution for a couple of days now. I have tried every possible solution suggested but had no luck yet. The problem looks simple but i've not been able to get around it. 
     Although the code compiles and runs perfectly fine in Eclipse, it gives error while running through a CI job (Jenkins). Please see the error below.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project clctnnotificationservFunctionalTests: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
01:16:35 [ERROR] /clctnnotificationserv-ci-2959/workspace/clctnnotificationserv-ci-2959/clctnnotificationservFunctionalTests/src/test/java/com/paypal/collections/decision/tests/NotificationTest.java:[117,9] error: cannot find symbol
```

The problematic statement is :

```
user = PayPalAccountCreator.createUser(data);
```

i' m trying to call the static method createUser() which is in source folder "src/test/java" but a different package (NOTE : this method was present in different source folder "src/main/java" before, later moved it to same source folder due to this issue but it didn't solve it).

Here is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- Add exclusion to all in the below dependency to avoid SSLPeerAuthentication issue 
    when running rbo tests using RBOTestFramework -->

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.paypal.test.qi.jaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>Jaws</artifactId>
    <version>${jawsUserVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.test.qi.jaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaws-restclients</artifactId>
        <version>${jawsUserVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.test.qi.jaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaws-raptorinfra-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jawsUserVersion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.test.services</groupId>
        <artifactId>restclienttestng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.paypal.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>RiskTestUtilities</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.20</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>Bluefin-GUI</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.paypal.test.bluefin</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>Jaws</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.paypal.test</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jaws-asfclient-deps</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.paypal.test</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>false</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        com.ebay.raptor.build
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        build-info-maven-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.2.0-RELEASE,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>addscminfo</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore>true</ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Build step  :

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your build steps.

Comment: @pat i have edited the question to include build step

Comment: Are you able to build your project outside of Eclipse? If you are able to build your project from scratch from your terminal or command line, putting Jenkins to work is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to it. 
It was due to a variable that was defined in src/main/java folder but was being used in src/test/java. 
Once i moved the variable to src/test/java, everything was fine. I guess its probably due to the fact that java compiles src/test/java before src/main/java. Since the variable was present in a different source folder it couldn't find it hence the error "Cannot find symbol". Please correct if my understanding is wrong.